# All files are red under IntelliJ project pane

Tags: user-interface, mercurial, intellij-idea

My project pane in IntelliJ has all files and folder in red color instead of the typical black. I can't find documentation on what does this color mean and how to fix whatever caused it so that it appears black again.

I notice that when I click on these files and folders, then choose Menu->VCS->Mercurial. It asks if I want to add them into source control. These files are already in Mercurial, perhaps this is a Mercurial problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Refer to help: [File Status Highlights](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-status-highlights.html).

Comment: Ok. That means it is indeed a problem with the Mercurial plugin not recognizing where things are.

Answer (score 11):

This can happen if there is an error with you VCS. To repair this:

1. Navigate to `Settings` | `Version Control`
2. Select the mapping(s)
3. Click `[-]` icon or press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove the mapping or change the association to `None`