# IntelliJ Idea - redish modules in project tree

Tags: intellij-idea

I have problem with Idea 12.0.4
Sometimes when I try to import external module to my project it appears (all directories and files and module name at the top) in reddish colour. I don't know what is the reason and why for some projects and modules this problem does not occur.
"Reddish module" seems to be imported correctly. It is compilable from project level.
In order to test this case I removed from my project one of old properly imported modules and imported it back. After this operation it becomes to be reddish and there is no way to turn it back into black.
What does that mean and how to solve this annoying issue?
Original help unfortunately doesn't help :(

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [pretty similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807610/all-files-are-red-under-intellij-project-pane).

In a few words this means that you have a problem with your VCS. You should configure it proper way and color will change.

Comment: But I don't use any VCS for this project! And this reddish colour does not match any of those listed here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-status-highlights.html

Comment: And it was never used before for thus modules? Then screenshot will be preferred.

Comment: Sorry - You're right. I had old, unused .svn directory one level above my test project. Seems that removing it solved the problem. It didn't influence existing modules - only those newly imported. Regards